# How do social apps like buffer posts to googe plus profile

Tags: google-plus, social-networking, google-domain-api

I have been reading google+ API and domain API and found out that google+ API are read-only. And domain API is only for domain users. But somehow I just tried [buffer](https://buffer.com/), connected my google+ profile and shared some text. It appeared in the posts section. Now my profile was not a part of a domain, it was `username@gmail.com`. Also, there are other social products which give the same functionality.

How do this work?

Comment: Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Answer (score 0):

Your app can share post on the behalf of the user on Google plus. All you need to do is take the appropriate permission from the user.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write Required - Grants
>   permission for the app to create posts or comments on behalf of a
>   user. The Google+ Domains API only allows creation of restricted
>   posts, and only allows comments to be added to restricted posts.

Ref : https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating

Comment: But looking to the documentation is says that API is read-only. To write use domain API, and that is restricted to the same domain account.

Comment: could you please share specific link of this documentation

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/acl This is access control. I Don't know If this helps or not. check out.

Comment: It is for only domain if you read through all of them, it states`limited to those within the domain`.

Answer (score -1):

There is an open authentication specification called oAuth that utilizes public api's, for instance: GitHub. Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, Google, Slack, etc. I believe the easiest way to implement this strategy is either with a bot, webhook, or my choice api framework Express.

Express has a middleware library called Passport that enables a quick setup of the necessary steps to implement the correct api keys, secrets and callbacks. Essentially what you have to do is create an app with each provider and they will give you the api information necessary for your Passport configuration.

Once you've got that done, then you just hook up a simple router and server, then you've got an app that can allow your users to sign into whichever provider they choose. The beauty behind the solution is their password information is serialized inside a JSON store to prevent security issues.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/

Comment: Read my question again, OAuth will give me token to read/write. But in case of Google+ API its only read, how do I write?

Comment: Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Comment: Even with OAuth token, I am not able to write